# Lensing in my raycasting engine

Tags: java

In my raycasting engine I have this really irritating bug.
If the player comes close to an object there is a huge lensing effect.
I already looked at this question and tried the fix he suggested.
Here is the code in my current implementation of the raycasting part (it is located in my paint method) I also Draw text to the screen afterwards.

```
double distance;
double lineHeight=-1;
double angleOff;            
double angleCast;
for(int i=0;i<900;i++){
    //i is the line across from the side.
    angleOff=Math.atan(((i-450.0)/4000.0)/.1);
    boolean hit=false;
    board.setColor(GameFrame.m.getBackground());
    board.drawLine(i, 922, i, 0);
    for( double rayDist=0;!hit;rayDist+=.01){
        try{
            char block=Map.map[(int) (Map.p.x+Math.sin(angleOff+Map.p.angle)*rayDist)][(int) (Map.p.y-Math.cos(angleOff+Map.p.angle)*rayDist)];
            if(block!='o'){
                lineHeight=800/(rayDist*Math.abs(Math.cos(angleOff+Map.p.angle)));
                switch(block){
                  case 'w':
                      board.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                      break;
                  case 'z':
                      board.setColor(Color.red);
                      break;
                  case 'g':
                      board.setColor(Color.green);
                      break;
                  case 'a':
                      board.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
                      break;
                }
                hit=true;
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            hit=true;
            lineHeight=800/(rayDist*Math.abs(Math.cos(angleOff+Map.p.angle)));
            board.setColor(Color.black);
        }
    }

    board.drawLine(i,(int) (461-(lineHeight/2)), i,(int) (461+(lineHeight/2)));
}
```

Note that `Map.p.angle` is the angle (from facing up) in radians of the player object.
Also note that the Map is stored as a `char[][]` where 'w' is a wall, 'z' is a zombie, 'g' is a gun powerup and 'a' is ammo.
If someone could let me know what is causing this lensing I will be very greatful.
Here are some screenshots
Normal function
[image: See how currently it looks (passably) 3d]
Bug
[image: Note the huge fisheye lensing effect]
Another Image
[image]

If anyone can tell me what correction needs to applied I will be very satisfied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue.
It is i this line
             lineHeight=800/(rayDist*Math.abs(Math.cos(angleOff+Map.p.angle)));
it should be
             lineHeight=800/(rayDist*Math.abs(Math.cos(angleOff)));
this made my code work well at angles near 0 but the bigger the angle was the more distortion